# How can I make a GUI for my C# XNA game?

Tags: c#, user-interface, xna

My game has basic functionality and is playable with a command line, but I would like to put a GUI on top of it.

It is a platformer type game written in C# with the XNA framework.

I have googled and found a few libraries, but they all seem very gum and duct tape. Is there a mature or standard way of making a GUI for my situation?

Comment: A command line platformer? I'm really curious :) Is it possible to view it somewhere?

Comment: "Is there a mature or standard way of making a GUI for my situation?" -- Not really, unfortunately.

Comment: @Paola I mean I can use the CLI just to test different features while I develop it, not for actual game play ;)

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer is: look at the Gamestate management tutorial [in Education Catalog](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management).

This doesn't give you very nice widgets, but rather shows a way of managing the game flow and some menus (including pause menu).

Comment: This is now a broken link with Microsoft's new phone or xbox page.

Comment: @AdamKDean Thanks, link fixed (tip: just add 'xbox.' after 'http://' to all old URLs).

Comment: Ah excellent, I didn't know that's how you fixed them. Amazing, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[NEOForce Controls](http://neoforce.codeplex.com/)

Full featured, open source GUI library for XNA 4.