# MessageBox & Dialogs on XNA (C#)

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, messagebox, dialogresult

I'm having the following code as part of my XNA game:

```
    private void gameOver()
    {
        if (!m_IsGameOver)
        {
            string message = String.Format("GAME OVER!!!{0}Your score is: {1}",
                        Environment.NewLine, GameScore);
            if (MessageBox.Show(message, "GameOver", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.Exit();
            }

            m_IsGameOver = true;
        }
    }

    private void gameWon()
    {
        string message = String.Format("You Won!!!{0}Your score is: {1}",
                    Environment.NewLine, GameScore);
        if (MessageBox.Show(message, "You Won!", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.Exit();
        }
    }
```

For some reason,I received the following errors:

```
"The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context"  
"The name 'MessageBoxButtons' does not exist in the current context"    
"The name 'DialogResult' does not exist in the current context"
```

I'm tring to add "System.Windows..." but it seems like that "System" does not have "windows" in it...

How can I solve this?

Comment: I wasn't aware to that,I've just did it now :)

Comment: Why are you mixing XNA and WinForms libraries? Instead of using the MessageBox, you should be displaying your messages via your game interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use WinForms classes in XNA. However, according to the docs, WinForms is not included in XNA: As can be seen in the [`MessageBox` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx), none of the `MessageBox` methods has the XNA logo in the first column, which means that none of them is supported in XNA. (See, for contrast, the [docs on `System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx), where all methods have the *X*-shaped XNA logo next to them).

For in-game GUIs, various solutions such as [this one](http://xnagui.codeplex.com/) exist; more links are included in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628265/how-can-i-make-a-gui-for-my-c-sharp-xna-game), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749294/is-there-any-free-xna-ui-library) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561541/xna-and-gui-controls-eg-xaml-and-xna) and [this MSDN forum posting](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/15274/79912.aspx) contains another list of links.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution...
Very simple :/
Adding the "System.Windows" to the "References" section in the project :)

Comment: As far as I can tell from statements on e.g. [this site](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1) and [this site](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/30455.aspx), non-PC XNA environments such as Xbox don't support WinForms. That means, your game will not run there if you reference WinForms. Also note that `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` (which you're attempting to use in your question) is in `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.

Comment: It can work though, but only if you've no plans to port it to other non-PC platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you try to bring in System.Windows.Forms, and you are using XNA's keys, like Keys.Up, there will be a name conflict with System.Windows.Forms Keys.