# How to save the response in a custom made popup dialog

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm trying to create a custom popup in xna that displays some text and adds the choice to select `yes` or `no`. Depending on the button selected, a value should be returned. I have everything pretty much set up, but I can't figure out how to do this particular part.

First, I have a `PopupDialogHandler` class which holds a list of all the `Popup_Dialog`'s and manages their respective `click` event and also manages updates and drawing.

The class `Popup_Dialog` is the class that manages creating a new `popup` object.

Everything is done, I draw the rectangle, draw the text, the button's are being handled, but I don't know what way should I use for a simple, yet effective result management.

Something like winforms' `MessageBox.Show` that returns.
Currently, I create `Popup_Dialog` object and add it to the list in `PopupDialogHandler` class, from there I loop through all the items in the list and do the drawing and updating logic

Comment: This is very broad. Can you post some code and maybe focus your question a little better?

Comment: Back in my XNA days, I had a `Closed` event on my dialog box that triggered when the dialog box was closed (e.g. someone clicked Ok or whatever). The `Closed` event passed along a `DialogClosedEventArgs` object that contained the dialog result, etc.

Comment: @Verdolino, I think more could would just make it more complicated. I just need to know which direction to go. I don't know where to start to accomplish my goal.

Comment: @val would you take some vb.net code? I have a custom messagebox written.

Comment: @Verdolino, sure, anything.

Comment: @val actually, it won't work. I didn't realize xna doesn't work with System.Windows.Forms. I would look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815283/messagebox-dialogs-on-xna-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Actions. In the PopupDialog class, add `private Action<int> Callback;` to the properties and this code to the constructor:

```
public PopupDialog(Action<int> callback /*, rest of constructor parameters if any */)
{
    /* Rest of constructor code, if any */

    if (callback == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    Callback = callback;
}
```

In the Click handler, just call `Callback()` with the value you want to return as the parameter.

In the receiving/waiting class, add this code:

```
private void CallbackFunction(int theReturnedValue)
{
    // do something with the value here
}
```

and pass the function like this when creating the new popup:

```
var RC = new PopupDialog(CallbackFunction);
```